# Visual Studio elements not showing on build

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have a 6x6 grid and beneath it, I have a label, two buttons and a text box. When I press start I can only see my grid, but no other objects are visible.
I tried setting each one visible status in XAML, but didn't work either.

Everything is visible in designer.

I never experienced this before, can you help?

Comment: Well I don't know what code to give you. My C# code doesn't include anything to do with these controls, and only if you want XAML code?

Comment: Yup. Your xaml would be helpful :)

Comment: Sure... It's a bit longer so here's a link to pastebin! I'm new to XAML so don't be mad if there are any mistakes :P
http://pastebin.com/aYpHGvVu

Comment: Why do you need so many rectangles?

Comment: Remove `Margins` from your controls. They are completely messed up and try to give them explicitly.

Comment: I needed 36 rectangles in a 6x6 grid and every rectangle has to have changeable color on click. Also, I'll try margins but I though that they are entered automatically when I move my controls in designer